# Netty: Stream response to the client as they become availabe

Tags: java, http, stream, netty

I have a Netty server that receives a POST request from a client with a json payload similar to:

```
{
  "url": [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.yahoo.com",
    "https://www.duckduckgo.com"
  ]
}
```

Then Netty server will send a GET request to each individual url in the "url" json array and send to the client the response body of each these requests.

The following code does exactly this.

```
private void handleJsonRequest(JsonNode requestNode, Channel channel) throws ParseRequestException {
    List<AuctionRequest> requestList = parseRequestJson(requestNode, getRequestStartTime(channel));

    requestList
      .stream()
      .map(auctionRequest -> {
          log.info("Going to send a request");
          CompletableFuture<AuctionRequestResult> response = getHttpClient().performRequest(auctionRequest);

          return response;
      })
      .forEach(future -> {
          onRequestComplete(channel, future);
      });
}
```

But I want to send to the client each response from the GET request sent to each url as they become available. Example:

1. A client sends a list of URLs (http://www.google.com, http://www.yahoo.com and http://www.duckduckgo.com) to the Netty server
2. Netty sends a GET request to http://www.google.com, http://www.yahoo.com and to http://www.duckduckgo.com
3. A few milliseconds later Netty receives the response from GET http://www.google.com but **not yet** from the other two URLs. So now I want to send the response from GET http://www.google.com to the client and still wait for the GET response from the other two URLs.
4. One second after Netty get the response from GET https://www.duckduckgo.com and I want to use the same connection as used in point 2 to send to the client the response body from the GET https://www.duckduckgo.com
5. Two seconds later Netty get the response from GET https://www.yahoo.com and perform the same action performed in step 3 and close the channel and end the response to the client.

The diagram below shows this flux of requests

[image: Data flux]

I know this is a good use case for server side events or websockets but this is not a possibility for now.

I have tried using `multi-part` response and using the `octet/stream` headers but only the first response is sent to the client, any posterior responses are not received by the client. Now I am trying to follow the chuncked response approach following [these instructions from another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305776/how-to-stream-a-response-over-http-with-netty) but to no success. Only the first response from the 3 (or more) requests Netty sends out is received by the client.

This is how I implemented the `onComplete` method that processes every response Netty receives

```
private void onRequestComplete(Channel channel, CompletableFuture<AuctionRequestResult> future) {
    future.whenComplete((requestResult, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable != null) {
            log.debug("Writing error response for request {}", future.hashCode());

            sendError(throwable.getMessage(), throwable, channel);
            log.debug("Finished writing error response for request {}", future.hashCode());
            return;
        }

        log.info("Writing response for request {}", future.hashCode());
        writeRequestResult(requestResult, channel);
        log.info("Finished writing response for request {}", future.hashCode());
    });
}


private void writeRequestResult(AuctionRequestResult requestResult, Channel channel) {
    ByteBuf buf = getByteBufAllocator().directBuffer(512000);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = getJsonWriter();
    try {
        // Create DTO and serialize it
        ProxyResponseDto proxyResponseDto = new ProxyResponseDto("ok", requestResult);
        dslJson.serialize(jsonWriter, proxyResponseDto);

        // Write response to the client
        writeResponse(channel, jsonWriter.getByteBuffer(), jsonWriter.size(), false);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage());
        closeChannel(channel);
    } 
    finally {
        buf.release();
        jsonWriter.reset();
        jsonWriters.offer(jsonWriter);
    }
}


private void writeResponse(Channel channel, byte[] responseJsonUtf8, int length) {
    String responseJson = new String(responseJsonUtf8);
    ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(responseJsonUtf8, 0, responseJsonUtf8.length);
    FullHttpRequest request = getRequestObject(channel);

    log.info("Writing response back in the channel");

    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
    response.headers().set(TRANSFER_ENCODING, CHUNKED);
    response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, "keep-alive");

    ChunkedInput<ByteBuf> chunkedInput = new ChunkedStream(new ByteBufInputStream(buf));
    HttpChunkedInput httpChunkedInput = new HttpChunkedInput(chunkedInput);

    // Write the response.
    if (channel.isActive()) {
        channel.write(response);
        ChannelFuture future = channel.writeAndFlush(httpChunkedInput);

        future.addListener(listener -> {
            if(listener.isSuccess()) {
                log.info("Wrote data to channel with success!!!");
            }
            else {
                log.error("Error when writting data to channel");
                Throwable cause = listener.cause();

                if(cause != null) {
                    log.error("Error reason: ", cause);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        log.warn("Exchange connection went dead. Ms from start: {}", (System.currentTimeMillis() - getRequestStartTime(channel)));
        closeChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

This is the log output. As you can see, the first response is successfully sent from Netty to the client but any further attempt throws an Exception

```
Calling onComplete
End of calling onComplete
Writing response for request 1897031616
Writing response back in the channel
Finished writing response for request 1897031616
Wrote data to channel with success!!!
Writing response for request -990888115
Writing response back in the channel
Error when writting data to channel
Error reason: 
io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent (expected: HttpResponse)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107) ~[netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.write(MessageToMessageCodec.java:116) ~[netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:708) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:791) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:701) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:696) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.doFlush(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:276) ~[netty-handler-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.flush(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:135) ~[netty-handler-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$2100(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:56) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1150) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1073) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:405) [netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:338) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.36.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906) [netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent (expected: HttpResponse)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.ensureHeaders(HttpContentEncoder.java:241) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.encode(HttpContentEncoder.java:97) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.encode(HttpContentEncoder.java:52) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec$1.encode(MessageToMessageCodec.java:67) ~[netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89) ~[netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    ... 20 more
```

My question is, can someone point me in the right direction in implementing a push/stream approach and send the data from Netty server to the client as it comes available without the usage of websockets or server side events?

Comment: Ignoring all the other problems with your code (e.g. thread safety) and that you are trying to tweak more functionality out of the HTTP protocol than what is supported, which may not work at all due to factors outside your control: Where is the exception thrown? I never understand why people don't include stack traces when they are logging exceptions. The direct cause for your issue is probably that you are trying to create several complete HTTP responses as the result of a single HTTP request (not possible), but without a stack trace, that is a pure guess.

Comment: @jarnbjo I just edited my question and added the full stacktrace

Comment: @jarnbjo I suspect you are correct when you say that I am "trying to create several complete HTTP responses as the result of a single HTTP request (not possible)". This is my first time with a plain Netty server so I am still grasping it

Comment: So don't do it. The solution to your problem is that the client makes three separate HTTP requests to your netty server, one for each url and then handles the responses as they come. Even if you can't use web sockets, there is with your requirements no reason to try to force more functionality out of the HTTP protocol than what is was ment to provide.

Comment: @jarnbjo Your point (the client making the three requests) is valid but unfortunately it cannot be applied to our use case. Shouldn't a multi-part response from Netty to the client be able to send the data to the client as it comes available?

Comment: Even if Netty may be able to send the data as it becomes available, you have no way to guarantee that it will arrive at the client when sent. In the real world, forced HTTP proxies, which are doing deep inspection of the reponse and all kinds of other strange things are not uncommon. They may very well wait for the entire response to become available before forwarding anything at all to the actual client.